# Diameter of ball's intersection with a halfspace

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $B(0, 1+2\delta)$ denote Euclidean ball centred at the zero vector with radius $1+2\delta$. Additionally consider the hyperplane $H = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \; | \; x_{1} \geq 1\}$, where $x_{1}$ denotes the first entry of the vector $x$ with respect to the standard basis. Show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that the diameter of $B(0, 1+2\delta)\cap H$ is less than $\epsilon$.

This question is inspired by these series of [notes](https://web.archive.org/web/20210810042759/https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs683/2007sp/), and the end of the proof of Theorem 3 in week 3, in which the author states a simple application of Pythagoras gives the result, but I can't quite see how (see the last paragraph of the proof on page 6 in the week 3 lecture notes). I would like to find a more general proof that works for normed spaces (if such a result holds), but at this point would take a proof for Euclidean spaces.

Here is my attempt at a proof so far:

I have tried to bound the diameter in terms of $\delta$ first. First I consider the vectors

$$a = (1, \: 2\sqrt{\delta}\sqrt{\delta+1}, \; \dots, \; 0)$$

$$b = (1, \: -2\sqrt{\delta}\sqrt{\delta+1}, \; \dots, \; 0)$$

I believe these vectors attain the diameter with $\|a - b\| = 4\sqrt{\delta}\sqrt{\delta+1}$. **I am struggling to prove that the diameter cannot be greater than this.** If this is the case, then we can select $\delta \geq 0$ such that:

$$4\sqrt{\delta}\sqrt{\delta + 1} \leq \epsilon$$

Or equivalently,

$$
16(\delta^{2} + \delta) \leq \epsilon^{2}
$$

Moving over $\epsilon^{2}$ to the LHS and applying the quadratic formula to solve for the root should yield a closed form for $\delta$ which satisfies our conditions, since the polynomial on the LHS is clearly increasing in $\delta$ for $\delta > 0$.

The previously mentioned lecture notes suggest choosing $\delta < \sqrt{1 + \epsilon^{2}/4} - 1$ **but I can't work out how they come to this conclusion**.

By completing the square I can get close:

$$
(\delta^{2} + \delta) \leq \epsilon^{2}/16 \\
(\delta + 1/2)^{2} - 1/4 \leq \epsilon^{2}/16 \\
(\delta + 1/2)^{2} \leq \epsilon^{2}/16 + 1/4 \\
\delta + 1/2 \leq \sqrt{\epsilon^{2}/16 + 1/4} \\
 \delta \leq \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\epsilon^{2}/4 + 1} - 1/2 \\
$$

but lose a factor of 1/2.

EDIT:#

Thanks to orangeskid answer, I think I have a better understanding of the problem. I have included an image which basically shows how Pythagoras can be applied.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

The diameter of an intersection $B\cap H$ ($B$ ball, $H$ halfspace) is $\operatorname{diam} B$ if $H$ contains the center of $B$, and $\operatorname{diam} (B\cap H_0)$, where $H_0$ is the boundary of $H$ otherwise. In your case, we have with Pythagoras
$$\operatorname{diam} (B\cap H_0)= 2 \sqrt{(1+2\delta)^2 - 1^2} = \cdots$$

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. I have added an image to the original answer, is this the correct interpretation? Additionally, I see intuitively why the diameter is attained on the boundary of the halfspace, but is there a proof you could perhaps link to or share?

Comment: @Nick Bishop: The image is correct. The diameter ( for a compact convex domain) is achieved between two extreme points. Now, the extreme points are the upper cupola, that is part of the sphere.  Now euclidian distance between two points on the sphere depends only on the opening angle, and that is largest for two opposite points on the intersection circle.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation!